# Sphinx - Increment max results

Tags: php, full-text-search, sphinx

I have a problem with Sphinx 2.2.11, I have a large indexes, when I set a limit greather than 13 elements, I don't receive any results. I think that the problem is due to a limit on packet size. I have just inserted in my sphinx.conf file the properties max_packet_size and mem_limit, but it still doesn't work even if I set limit to 14 elements. So how can I resolve it?

**UPDATE**

Here my configuration: [sphinx.conf](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/5026723f544dd87898c9db78d95a7c3220181004080602/fc2b31)

Comment: What does 'elements' mean? not sure its a standard term in sphinx, so unsure what you referring to.

Comment: Hi @Mintendo. If LIMIT 13 gives you 13 results, but LIMIT 14 gives you none I bet it's a bug somewhere. Please provide more details: your config, what client you're using, check in searchd and query logs. Provide what SHOW META and SHOW WARNINGS (or corresponding functions in your client) return after the query.

Comment: @Manticore-Sphinxnextgen If I run the query from my console with .\mysql.exe -P9306 it works, it doesn't work when I run from application using sphinxapi file. From searchd and query logs I don't receive any error

Comment: Can you check in your php error/warnings log as well and also do print_r($cl) where $cl is SphinxClient object and check if there's any warning/error there.

Comment: @Manticore-Sphinxnextgen I checked and I didn't receive any error/warnings neither in $cl object, neither in my php error_log file. I want to know if there's a default limit in Sphinx to get data, because if I use another index (that has less field in the select query, the limit of data that I can get is 307 records). Anyway I uploaded my conf file above

Comment: @Mintendo There's no default limit like this. Moreover since you say with mysql client it works fine the problem should be not in the searchd, but in the php client or in the application. Perhaps your php process runs out of memory, but you would get an error from that then unless the errors are muted. How does your response array look after the query which doesn't return the amount of data you expect? Does it still include correct total_found, time and words? Is the "matches" empty or missing at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that after get the results from sphinx, I converted them from array to object with the trick: `json_decode(json_encode($results))` and this caused an out of memory of the server.